# Writing to Named Cells in Excel from Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I've Searched Forums here and I can't seem to get this code to work.

I am Trying to Open a Workbook in Excel, and then populate a few of the Cells(Named Ranges). I can successfully open the workbook(the workbook has a bit of VBA that runs when it opens as well, formatting stuff only) but when I get down to the inputting information I get a 'Run-Time Error "438" Object Doesn't support this property or method.'

From the Previous answers on other similar questions I have done everything the way it was suggested however, I can't seem to get it to work.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub MaterialInput()

Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim RsClient As Recordset
Dim RsJobsite As Recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim ClientSTR As String
Dim JobsiteSTR As String
Dim customer As Variant

Set db = CurrentDb
JobsiteSTR = "SELECT T1Jobsites.JobsiteNickName FROM T1Jobsites WHERE T1Jobsites.JobsiteID = 1" ' & Form_LEM.TxtJobsiteID
Set RsJobsite = db.OpenRecordset(JobsiteSTR, dbOpenSnapshot, dbSeeChanges)

ClientSTR = "SELECT T1Companies.CompanyName " & _
            "FROM T1Companies INNER JOIN T1Jobsites ON T1Companies.CompanyID = T1Jobsites.CompanyId " & _
            "WHERE (((T1Jobsites.JobsiteID)=1))"
'ClientSTR = "SELECT T1Companies.CompanyName FROM T1Companies INNER JOIN T1Jobsites ON T1Companies.CompanyID = T1Jobsites.CompanyID" & _
                " WHERE T1JobsitesID = 1" '& Form_LEM.TxtJobsiteID
Set RsClient = db.OpenRecordset(ClientSTR, dbOpenSnapshot, dbSeeChanges)

Set xlapp = CreateObject("excel.application")


Set wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\coc33713\Desktop\VISION - EXCEL FILES\VISIONCOUNT.xlsm")
Set ws = xlapp.Worksheets("CountSheet")
xlapp.Visible = True

'Tried this second after reading another forum
'the comments Recordset will be the actual values used, but I can't get the String "TEST" to work

wb.ws.Range("Client").Value = "TEST"      'RsClient!CompanyName

'Tried this way first
xlapp.ws.Range("'SiteName'").Value = "Test"        'RsJobsite!JobsiteNickName"
xlapp.ws.Range(Date).Value = "Test"          'Form_LEM.TxtDate
xlapp.ws.Range(ProjectName).Value = "Test"     'Form_LEM.TxtPlant
xlapp.ws.Range(ScaffoldID).Value = "Test"    'Form_LEM.cboScaffnum.Value
xlapp.ws.Range(ScaffoldNumber).Value = "Test"       'Form_LEM.cboScaffnum.Column(1)

Set xlapp = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
Set RsClient = Nothing
Set RsJobsite = Nothing
Set db = Nothing


End Sub
```

[As a Sidenote this is not a form it is just spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPDY4.jpg)
Thank you everyone!

Comment: FWIW (not your issue - that is solved by Scott's answer): Note that `Set ws = xlapp.Worksheets("CountSheet")` should be `Set ws = wb.Worksheets("CountSheet")`.  Using `xlapp.Worksheets("CountSheet")` is effectively `xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CountSheet")` which **might be** (and probably is) `xlApp.Workbooks("VISION - EXCEL FILES\VISIONCOUNT.xlsm").Worksheets("CountSheet")` but it is better to do it correctly rather than leave it to chance.

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks this little miss, is the right answer Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ws.Range("Client").Value = "Test"
```

Or

```
Dim sName as String
sName = "Client"

ws.Range(sName).Value = "Test"
```

Reason being is that you have the `ws` object set already, so there is no need to assign parentage to it again. In fact, trying to do so will break syntax rules.

Comment: Thanks I did take into account your answer but it did turn out to be a missed declaration. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

FWIW (not your issue - that is solved by Scott's answer): Note that
 `Set ws = xlapp.Worksheets("CountSheet"`) 
should be 
`Set ws = wb.Worksheets("CountSheet")`.

Using `xlapp.Worksheets("CountSheet")`
is effectively `xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CountSheet")` which might be (and probably is) `xlApp.Workbooks("VISION - EXCEL FILES\VISIONCOUNT.xlsm").Worksheets("CountSheet")` but it is better to do it correctly rather than leave it to chance.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
Sub DAOFromExcelToAccess()
' exports data from the active worksheet to a table in an Access database
' this procedure must be edited before use
Dim db As Database, rs As Recordset, r As Long
    Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\FolderName\DataBaseName.mdb") 
    ' open the database
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("TableName", dbOpenTable) 
    ' get all records in a table
    r = 3 ' the start row in the worksheet
    Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0 
    ' repeat until first empty cell in column A
        With rs
            .AddNew ' create a new record
            ' add values to each field in the record
            .Fields("FieldName1") = Range("NamedRange1").Value
            .Fields("FieldName2") = Range("NamedRange2").Value
            .Fields("FieldNameN") = Range("NamedRangeN").Value
            ' add more fields if necessary...
            .Update ' stores the new record
        End With
        r = r + 1 ' next row
    Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```